# Не получается добавить водяной знак на всплывающую картинку в fancybox

Tags: html, jquery, css, fancybox, изображения

Всем привет! Хочу добавить watermark на всплывающую картинку в fancybox - никак не выходит. Что не так?

```js
$(".fancybox-wrap").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function() {
    $('.fancybox-inner').append('<img id="watermark-inner" src="http://plasmate.ru/images/design/rek_vkon.png" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;" />')
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <? u_img(101); ?>
      <p>
        <? u_txt(101); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <? u_img(102); ?>
      <p>
        <? u_txt(102); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <? u_img(103); ?>
      <p>
        <? u_txt(103); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: никто не знает или недостаточно инфы от меня?

Answer (score 1):

Зашел на http://fancybox.net

Поискал пример с келбеками, нашел вот что в коде страницы примеров:

```
$("#various7").fancybox({
    onStart     :   function() {
        return window.confirm('Continue?');
    },
    onCancel    :   function() {
        alert('Canceled!');
    },
    onComplete  :   function() {
        alert('Completed!');
    },
    onCleanup   :   function() {
        return window.confirm('Close?');
    },
    onClosed    :   function() {
        alert('Closed!');
    }
});
```

Указанного вами триггера нет в списке, попробуйте воспользоваться `onComplete`

И вообще, ватермарки накладываются на сами изображения при их загрузке на сайте. То, что вы делаете по сути фикция.

Comment: ок, попробую. А к какому классу нужно применять fancybox - может я что-то не правильно делаю?

Comment: неа, как ни старался, какие только классы и триггеры не использовал - не выходит..